# golang : invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

Tags: go

Execute me
Now I have a program called `HelloWorld`, and the Project structure is
[image]

`aaa.go`

```
package aaa

import (
    "HelloWorld/test/bbb"
)

var aa = bbb.Bb

func World() {
    aa.Hello()
}
```

`bbb.go`

```
package bbb

import "HelloWorld/test/ccc"

var Bb *ccc.Config
```

`ccc.go`

```
package ccc

import "fmt"

type Config struct {
    C int
}

func ConfigInit() *Config {
    return &Config{C: 10}
}

func (c *Config) Hello() {
    fmt.Println(c.C)
}
```

`main.go`

```
package main

import (
    "HelloWorld/test/aaa"
    "HelloWorld/test/bbb"
    "HelloWorld/test/ccc"
)

func init() {
    bbb.Bb = ccc.ConfigInit()
}

func main() {

    aaa.World()
}
```

now when i run the program, it will `panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference`

but when i change the `main.go`

```
import (
    "HelloWorld/test/bbb"
    "HelloWorld/test/ccc"
)

func init() {
    bbb.Bb = ccc.ConfigInit()
}

func main() {

    // aaa.World()
    var aa = bbb.Bb
    aa.Hello()
}
```

It can output the correct value `10`
I don't know why the definition `var aa = bbb.Bb` in the `bbb.go`is incorrect

I don't understand why it's a null pointer

Comment: Ask yourself: When is aaa.aa set? See?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

If you look at the above picture,it shows the import and variable initialization flow. Now, in the first case `aaa.world`. The variable `aa` in world function is set to `nil` because even before the init function in the main runs, once the init runs `bb` points to valid memory but before it, bb in package `bbb` was never initialized in the first place. Let's take the second case into account, here also the init function gives bb a valid memory, but the catch here is that `aa` is reassigned to bb which points to valid memory and so does `aa` after the assignment.